# Can not install new packages

Tags: apt

Getting this message:

```
alkos@vps-21314:/root$ sudo apt-get -f install mailutils                                                                                                                                                                                  
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                         
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                                                                                                                                                           
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                           
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                           
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-77-generic but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                                          
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                                                           
 mailutils : Depends: mailutils-common (= 1:2.99.99-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                                         
             Depends: default-mta or                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                      mail-transport-agent                                                                                                                                                                                                
             Depends: guile-2.0-libs but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                                                                  
             Depends: libmailutils4 (>= 1:2.99.99) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                                                                    
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

None of the `apt-get -f install` , `sudo apt-get update && time`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` work for me, getting the same message from the server, what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to make sure that all of the repositories are checked, and a valid nearby Server is chosen, under the Ubuntu Software tab in `Software & Updates`, and then do `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: You seem to have unwisely added a non-Ubuntu source which provides packages that are *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. Delete the source, and uninstall ALL packages from that source. Then your package manager will work again.  Next time, be more selective in your choice of non-Ubuntu sources.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I normally use `aptitude`, which has a much more powerful depedency solver engine. The command is quite the same, `sudo aptitude install mailutils`. It will begin to propose you various solutions, asking you to confirm or go to the next solution. Be careful with the choice, as sometimes it will remove some dependencies which are vital to the system (it happened to me, as I didn't carefully read that the proposed solution was going to remove vital packages)